# Spring Transaction @Transactional annotation not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

```java
@Transactional(rollbackFor = someException.class)
public void methodA() throws someException {
    try {
        methodB();
    } catch (someException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}


public void methodB() throws someException {
    try {

        someManager.save(object); // This object should only save when the whole transaction is committed

        callToSomeOtherServer(); // This call fails and throws exception

    } catch () {
        throw new someException();
    }
}
```

According to my understanding, in **methodB()** we are saving an **object** with someManager and calling another function **callToSomeOtherServer()**. So this is part of a transaction in the upper method. If **callToSomeOtherServer()** fails and throws **someException**, the whole transaction should be rolled back and the saved object should not reflect in the DB.

But this is not working for me, the object is reflected in DB. Can someone help and make me understand why is it not working?

Comment: Please refer:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188239/spring-transaction-rollback-on-exception-or-throwable

Comment: Instead of rollbackFor = someException.class, try rollbackFor = Exception.class

Comment: @dassum I have referred this. Still the issue prevails!

Comment: Tried, still not working @uneq95.

Comment: Please check methodB is throwing someException only. Also, it will be helpful if you can share the stack trace.

Comment: Which database are you using, please add your configuration.

Comment: You don't need to catch and rethrow the exception, it only hinders readability here. Are you using Spring Boot or are you manually configuring transaction management ? if this is the case please paste your Configuration classes or XML config

Comment: Any chance you are [calling `methodA` from the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423972/spring-transaction-method-call-by-the-method-within-the-same-class-does-not-wo) ?

Comment: Regardless the actual problem, and assuming the `callToSomeOtherServer` call doesn't need the object to be persisted (it won't until the transaction ends, anyway), I'd suggest rearranging the calls, so the persist line isn't reached when the external call throws the exception.

Comment: Why do you catch an exception and again throw the same exception?

Comment: @Hargur: can you show the code from where you are calling this method.

Answer (score 0):

Try This!
 `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false, timeout = 100, rollbackFor = Exception.class)`