# Transactional anotation with expection

Tags: java, spring

I want my transaction to be canceled following a personalized exception

```
@Transactional
public class MyClass{

    public void step1() throws Exception {
        throw new java.lang.Exception();
    }
    public void step2() throws Exception {
        throw new java.lang.Exception();
    }


}
```

But nothing happens when my exceptions occur.

Comment: not sure if I followed, but are you looking for `rollbackFor` https://stackoverflow.com/q/21188239/2704032?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal, by default spring canceled only when an unchecked exception is thrown.

you have to add at the top of your class @Transactional ( rollbackFor =  Exception . class ).

Like that

```
@Transactional ( rollbackFor =  Exception.class )

public class MyClass{

    public void step1() throws Exception {
        throw new java.lang.Exception();
    }
    public void step2() throws Exception {
        throw new java.lang.Exception();
    }


}
```

Now like that your exception can cancel your transaction.